# Turbolinks 5 : Show progress Bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

There is a progress bar when Turbolinks.visit is called.

I want to show and hide it manually (because some of my xhr request are a bit long), is it possible?

(In Turbolinks 3, there was Turbolinks.ProgressBar.start(); but it was not a public api and not working anymore)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turbolinks 5 has the ProgressBar instance deeper in the singleton controller object. The following should work:

```
function safeStartTurbolinksProgress() {
  if(!Turbolinks.supported) { return; }
  Turbolinks.controller.adapter.progressBar.setValue(0);
  Turbolinks.controller.adapter.progressBar.show();
}

function safeStopTurbolinksProgress() {
  if(!Turbolinks.supported) { return; }
  Turbolinks.controller.adapter.progressBar.hide();
  Turbolinks.controller.adapter.progressBar.setValue(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Turbolinks.ProgressBar.disable()` at any point and make it go away. Or you can even make your own progress bar by adding classes during these phases and using some CSS wizardry.

```
if Turbolinks.ProgressBar
  // Do stuff

$(document).on 'page:fetch', ->
  // Do stuff while the fetch is starting

$(document).on 'page:receive', ->
    // It's almost done

$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  // It's done

$(document).on 'page:restore', ->
  // It's really done
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 (Turbolinks 5), the progress bar is enabled by default. It appears automatically for any page that takes longer than 500ms to load.

To disable the progress bar entirely, set its visibility style to hidden:

```
.turbolinks-progress-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#advanced-usage).